# How to handle ACTIVATION_FAILED

Tags: docusignapi

I am creating an embedded signing experience within our web app, so have turned off the sending of emails by DocuSign. Our app will send any emails required itself.

The DocuSign envelope has a single recipient with an access code defined.

I use the [createRecipient](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient/) envelope view in order to get the DocuSign URL at which the recipient can sign the document.

When accessing this URL, the recipient is prompted to enter their access code. If instead of entering the access code, they click the **I NEVER RECEIVED AN ACCESS CODE** button, they get taken to the return URL with the event parameter set to XXX.

This is all working as I would expect.

However, if I then try to call the [createRecipient](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient/) function again for the envelope, I get an error response from the API:

```
{
  "errorCode": "ACTIVATION_FAILED",
  "message": "The token for a recipient that has failed activation cannot be generated."
}
```

If I login to the DocuSign site and look at the envelope, it shows an error message:

> **Authentication Failed**: Resend to give recipient another chance to pass authentication, or correct to remove or change authentication details.

The envelope appears to be in a locked state.

I can click **RESEND** in the DocuSign site, or do a [PUT request](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/update/) to the envelope via the API with `?resend_envelope=true` and this results in the envelope "unlocking" and allows the call to the [createRecipient](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient/) envelope view to succeed.

However, this results in an email being sent by DocuSign to the user, which I don't want.

Can anyone advise how to unlock an envelope/recipient in an ACTIVATION_FAILED state without sending emails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the same flow and it works fine for me and I am not getting an email when clicking RESEND in the DocuSign site, or do a PUT request to the envelope via the API with ?resend_envelope=true. Please find the below steps which I took to replicate the issue:

- Created an envelope with recipient with clientUserId as not null
- Generated RecipientView Url using clientUserId
- User was    presented with AccessCode, then I clicked "Never
  Received an Access    Code"
- Again tried to created RecipientView Url using clientUserId    and
  got ACTIVATION_FAILED error
- Then I tried below call
        `PUT    /restapi/v2/accounts/<accountId>/envelopes/<envelopeId>?resend_envelope=true`
  with blank body as

  {
          }
        Instead of Put call, I even tried using Resend button from Webconsole    and it also worked fine without triggering any email.
- I did not receive any email
- Now again tried to created RecipientView Url    using clientUserId,
  this time I could generate the URL and on opening    that URL, I
  could again get a screen to enter the Access Code

Comment: Thanks Amit, you are correct -- my bad.

When I viewed the Envelope History in the web console, there was a Resent record with the recipient's email address. I had mistakenly thought this meant an email had been sent.